# Animated mesh is glitching in cycles 3.5

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, rigging

I never encountered this problem before but on two different projects some  armature animated meshes start glitching (weird lines) on random frames in the render (not the viewport), as you can see on the photo. Any ideas on the reason ? I've tested the project in blender 3.3 and the problem isn't here...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on an actual problem, let alone a proper solution, but for the time being, I've noticed that moving the bones within the rig and setting a key seems to remove this weird vertex issue.

[image: Render of a frame with vertex issue]
[image: Same frame as prior render after moving the pose and setting a keyframe]

Comment: Thanks ! Can you explain your "moving the bones" fix ? I'm not sure I understand

Answer (score 0):

Just tried the moving bones thing. Indeed the glitch was gone. I went to an already keyframed point in my timeline, just moved (slightly rotating it will do) a bone a tiny bit, and keyframed it again.